# Implementation of menu buttons in WPF/MVVM/Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, datatemplate

I have a Region in the top left of the WPF application which I want to be my global button bar where the user chooses which screen they want to view, and the appropriate content will then be displayed in the main region. THere will also be a sub navigation region in the top right with sub-menu options within that screen, eg if the user clicked "Maintenance" from the main menu, the sub menu would show options for New, Update, Delete, Edit etc.

What I want to have is a way to create a custom menu bar by simply specifying a list of Text button names, and ICommand/Parameter pairs for the action to invoke on button click. The natural way to do this would be have a MenuButtonViewModel class with dependency properties Title, Command and CommandParameter. One more would also be needed, IsSelected, so there is some visual way for the user to see which screen you are currently on, so it needs to behave like a toggle button, but where only one button in the group can be selected at a time. I can then have a UserControl where the content of the bar binds to an ObservableCollection and uses data templates to render the button bar.

I have tried a few ways of doing this so far but cannot figure out a way that gives me the visual behaviour I want. These are my requirements

1) Button to change background to a different Brush OnMouseOver 
2) When button is selected, a different Brush is displayed as the background until a new button in the group is selected, like a togglebutton IsSelected behaviour
3) Only one button in the group can be selected at a time

The ways I have tried to do this so far are

1) Extending RadioButton with my own class, adding dependency properties for command and commandparameter. Setting all controls to have the same group Id. Data template to override display of radio button to make it look like a visual button with triggers for mouseover and isselected.

This works fine, except for one thing. Once you select a radio button in a group, there is no way to deselect all options in the radio button group. So if you navigate to "maintenance" and then click the sub menu for "Countries" for example, then you are displayed the country maintenance screen. If you then go to a different area of the app and select "Deal Entry" from the main menu, you are taken to the deal entry screen. If you then click "Maintenance", it displays the generic "maintenance" content and brings back the sub menu control for maintenance, where "Country" is selected in the radio button group, but this is undesirable. When you navigate back to Maintenance, it should deselect all sub menu options, display the generic maintenance landing page content and let you select a sub menu option before displaying that screens content. The first time you load Maintenance, nothing is selected, but once you have chosen an option, then there is no way to have nothing selected again when you reload the maintenance screen.

2) I then tried extending a ListBox, styling it with a horizontal stackpanel for the content, each listboxitem is a menubuttonViewModel. This allows me to only select a single option at a time and to clear the selection when you navigate away from the page. It also lets me change the background when you mouse over each listboxitem.

The bit I can't get working with the listbox is to have the background different on the IsSelected trigger. There seems to be some trigger on the default ListBoxItem template that overrides anything you specify in CSS so no matter what trigger I put on the listboxitem or menubuttonviewmodel style, the background simply does not change. I think I need to redefine the data and content template for listboxitem, but only have it apply for this listbox, so it can't be a global template change to all listboxitems - as I want to be able to use listboxes elsewhere in the app without inheriting this behaviour.

Can anyone give their thoughts on these two approaches and how to perhaps solve the issues I'm having to make one of them work in the way I want, particularly if you can advise how I can override the content/data template for the listboxitems in my style so they do not use the default triggers, and I can get the IsSelected trigger working for me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you would want to clear the selection on the **RadioButtons** from the **Sub-Menu** each time you ***navigate*** back from another **Main Menu** option.

In order to solve this, you could have every **Radio Button** *"unchecked"* by manually setting the **RadioButton´s IsChecked** property value to ***false***. A possible solution could be the following:

If you want to clear any checked option from the **Sub-Menu** everytime you navigate to a different section of the **Main Menu**, you could first notify to the **Sub-Menu´s ViewModel** by publishing an event using the **EventAggregator** after selecting and clicking a different **MainMenu** button, from the **SelectionChangedEventHandler** method of the **Main Menu´s ViewModel**.

Therefore, the **Sub-Menu EventHandler** of the published event would update each **RadioButton´s IsChecked** property value to ***false***, which it could be accomplished by using a **"Two-Way" Binding** between each **IsChecked** property defined on the **View**, and each boolean ***"RadioButton1IsChecked"*** property implemented on the **ViewModel**.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: Notice that this solution would apply to the first approach that you mentioned which it seems it would be more elegant and it was only a detail away in order to run properly.